# Creating a contact with Python throws out an AttributeError when I execute it on another client

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, win32com, office-automation

this is my first Python Programm.
I wanted to create a programm which takes data from an excel sheet and creates outlook contacts with the data.
I used pyinstallier to make an .exe out of it. On my client it is working also one some other computers.
But somehow on some clients it wont work. the error message pops up for half a second, the image is in the attachment below. here is my code:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import openpyxl

# Excel-Datei öffnen
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\PathToExcel\Gruppen.xlsx')

# Arbeitsblatt auswählen
worksheet = workbook['Tabelle2']  
outlook = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')


contacts = outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(10)  # 10 steht für den Standardordner "Kontakte"

existing_contacts = contacts.Items

# Schleife über alle Zeilen im Arbeitsblatt
for row in worksheet.iter_rows(values_only=True):
    name = row[0]
    email = row[1]

    # Überprüfen, ob der Kontakt bereits vorhanden ist
    existing_contact = next((c for c in existing_contacts if c.Email1Address == email), None)

    if existing_contact is not None:
        # Wenn der Kontakt bereits vorhanden ist, Nachname aktualisieren
        if existing_contact.LastName != name:
            existing_contact.LastName = name
            print("Kontakt akualisiert: ", existing_contact.Email1Address)
            existing_contact.Save()
    else:
        # Wenn der Kontakt noch nicht vorhanden ist, Kontakt erstellen und speichern
        contact = outlook.CreateItem(2)
        contact.LastName = name
        contact.Email1Address = email
        print("Kontakt neu erstellt: ", contact.Email1Address)
        contact.Save()
```

[Error Message on another Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn5Ud.jpg)

I tried to add `--hidden-import win32com.client --hidden-import openpyxl` to the pyinstaller command but it also wont help

Comment: I assume the error is occuring on the `contact.Email1Address = email` line. It only gets called when trying to create a contact that doesn't exist yet. To test this, you could try to run the program with an excel sheet that only contains 1 contact which already exists. This shouldn't throw an error. Also, running the code directly instead of as an exe file might give some more insights.

Comment: Where and when do you run the code?

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming you can only have `ContactItem` objects in the folder, but you can also have `DistListItem` (which does not expose `Email1Address` property).

You need to check that you indeed have a contact - check if `Class` property (exposed by all Outlook objects) == 40 (`OlObjectClass.olContact`)

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways of creating new Outlook items. You can using the `Items.Add` method instead.

Also I've noticed the following line of code where you iterate over all items in the folder:

```
existing_contact = next((c for c in existing_contacts if c.Email1Address == email), None)
```

Instead, you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class where you may get only items that correspond to the search criteria. Read more about these methods in the articles that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext to retrieve Outlook Contact items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/19/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-contacts/)
- [How To: Retrieve Outlook Contact items using Restrict method](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/21/outlook-retrieve-contact-items/)

The Outlook object model is common for all programming languages, so you can find what properties and methods should be used to get the job done right.